# Proportional font instead of monospaced on mobile in inline code blocks

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, code

On the mobile version of Stack Overflow, inline code blocks are still proportional instead of monospaced.

**Example**:

`Illogical1011111illllll`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile site doesn't show monospace font for codeblocks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296640/mobile-site-doesnt-show-monospace-font-for-codeblocks) and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260144/monospaced-font-in-code-blocks

Comment: Do you also get this for normal (large) code blocks in your case, or only inline ones ?